# Elements must match XML & DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

The validator says that there are some elements that must match the DTD.

I tried to validate it with the xml validator web and with the XML Copy editor.

This is the XML code:

```
<empresa>
    <empleados>
        <oficinistas>
            <oficinista>Juan Fernando</oficinista>
            <oficinista>Josue Gallardo</oficinista>
        </oficinistas>
        <tecnicos>
            <tecnico tipo="redes">Raul Rabufeti</tecnico>
            <tecnico tipo="cloud">Francisco Eberredi</tecnico>
            <tecnico tipo="teleco">Juan Carabán</tecnico>
            <tecnico tipo="tienda">Raul Gandolfi</tecnico>
        </tecnicos>
    </empleados>
    <tienda>
        <tecnicos>
            <tecnico>Roberto Cinyapies</tecnico>
            <tecnico>Antonio Martinez</tecnico>
            <tecnico>Pepe Pintamonas</tecnico>
        </tecnicos>
    </tienda>
    <departamentos>
        <pc>HP1</pc>
        <pc>HP2</pc>
        <pc>HP3</pc>

        <trabajador>Johan Lopez</trabajador>
        <trabajador>Jose Luis Gilberto</trabajador>
        <trabajador>Mario del Monte Quemado</trabajador>

        <tecnico>Hernesto Arreglatodo</tecnico>
    </departamentos>
    <oficinas>
        <jefe tipo="ceo">Cabroncito Ortega</jefe>
        <pc>Packard Bell 1</pc>
        <pc>Packard Bell 2</pc>
        <secretario>Pelotas Gil</secretario>
    </oficinas>
    <servicios>
        <nube>Cloud Computing</nube>
        <redes>Instalación de Redes</redes>
            <velocidad valor="300">300Mbps</velocidad>
            <velocidad valor="100">100Mbps</velocidad>
        <teleco>Antenas instalacion y mantenimiento</teleco>
        <hosting>Hosting Web</hosting>
            <almacenamiento tipo="normal">5GB</almacenamiento>
            <almacenamiento tipo="premium">10GB</almacenamiento>
        <servidores>Servidores centralizados</servidores>
            <servidor>IBM1</servidor>
            <servidor>IBM2</servidor>
        <presupuesto_coste>
            <montaje>25</montaje>
            <coste>15</coste>
        </presupuesto_coste>

        <componentes>
            <componente>
                <nombre>Grafica</nombre>
                <modelo>GTX 1050</modelo>
                <precio>150?</precio>
                <marca>Nvidia</marca>
            </componente>
            <componente>
                <nombre>Pantalla</nombre>
                <modelo>700</modelo>
                <precio>100?</precio>
                <marca>Aoc</marca>
            </componente>
            <componente>
                <nombre>Teclado y ratón</nombre>
                <modelo>564</modelo>
                <precio>35?</precio>
                <marca>Logitech</marca>
            </componente>
            <componente>
                <nombre>Torre</nombre>
                <modelo>795</modelo>
                <precio>600?</precio>
                <marca>Packard Bell</marca>
            </componente>
        </componentes>

        <presupuestos>
            <presupuesto tipo="alto">Gaming</presupuesto>
            <presupuesto tipo="medio">Basic</presupuesto>
            <presupuesto tipo="bajo">Low cost</presupuesto>
        </presupuestos>

    </servicios>
    <jefes>
        <jefe tipo="ceo">Jefe Master Pinche</jefe>
        <jefe tipo="ventas">Tolovendo Alegrez</jefe>
        <jefe tipo="marqueting">Compramelo Rapidez</jefe>
    </jefes>

    <clientes>
        <cliente codigo="x_01">Jose Luís</cliente>
        <cliente codigo="x_02">Jonh Petter</cliente>
        <cliente codigo="x_03">Kim Kardasian</cliente>
    </clientes>
</empresa>
```

The DTD code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT empresa (empleados,tienda,departamentos,oficinas,servicios,jefes,clientes)>
<!ELEMENT clientes (cliente*)>
<!ELEMENT cliente (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT empleados (oficinistas,tecnicos)>
<!ELEMENT oficinistas (oficinista+)>
<!ELEMENT oficinista (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT tecnicos (tecnico+)>
<!ELEMENT tecnico (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST tecnico tipo CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT tienda (tecnicos+)>
<!ELEMENT departamentos (pc+,trabajador+,tecnico+)>
<!ELEMENT trabajador (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT tabajadores (trabajador+)>
<!ELEMENT trabajadores (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT oficinas (jefe,pc+,secretario)>
<!ATTLIST jefe tipo CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT jefe (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT secretario (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT servicios (nube,redes,teleco,hosting,servidores,presupuesto_coste,componentes,presupuestos)>
<!ELEMENT nube (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT redes (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT teleco (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST velocidad valor (100|300) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST conexion tipo (fibra|cobre) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT conexion (tipo,velocidad)>
<!ELEMENT tipo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT velocidad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hosting (almacenamiento+)>
<!ELEMENT almacenamiento (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST almacenamiento tipo (normal|premium) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT servidores (servidor+)>
<!ELEMENT servidor (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT presupuesto_coste (montaje,coste)>
<!ELEMENT montaje (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT coste (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT componentes (componente+)>
<!ELEMENT componente (nombre,modelo,precio,marca)>
<!ELEMENT nombre (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT modelo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT precio (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT marca (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST componentes tipo (normal|gaming) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT presupuestos (presupuesto+)>
<!ELEMENT presupuesto (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST presupuesto tipo (alto|medio|bajo) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST presupuesto precio (500|700|1000) #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT jefes (jefe+)>
<!ATTLIST jefe ceo CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST jefe ventas CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST jefe marqueting CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST cliente codigo ID #REQUIRED>
```

And the errors, all are must match, why the validator shows the "+" symbol out of the "()" I don't understand, the XML validates correctly:

```
48: 39  The content of element type "hosting" must match "(almacenamiento)+".
    51: 58  The content of element type "servidores" must match "(servidor)+".
    92: 17  The content of element type "servicios" must match "(nube,redes,teleco,hosting,servidores,presupuesto_coste,componentes,presupuestos)".
```

Answer (score 0):

This DTD statement

```
<!ELEMENT hosting (almacenamiento+)>
```

says that the content model for the `<hosting>` element is one or more `<almacenamiento>` elements. So the XML file should look like this:

```
<hosting>
    <almacenamiento tipo="normal">5GB</almacenamiento>
    <almacenamiento tipo="premium">10GB</almacenamiento>
</hosting>
```

The same construct applies to

```
<!ELEMENT servidores (servidor+)>

<servidores>
    <servidor>IBM1</servidor>
    <servidor>IBM2</servidor>
</servidores>
```

The last error is associated with this DTD statement:

```
<!ELEMENT servicios (nube,redes,teleco,hosting,servidores,presupuesto_coste,componentes,presupuestos)>
```

The `<servicios>` element must consist of exactly one occurrence of of each element in the list, in the exact order, there are no optional elements. However,
the XML document contains two `<velocidad>` elements, which is not allowed.

```
<servicios>
    <nube>Cloud Computing</nube>
    <redes>Instalación de Redes</redes>
        <velocidad valor="300">300Mbps</velocidad>
        <velocidad valor="100">100Mbps</velocidad>
    <teleco>Antenas instalacion y mantenimiento</teleco>
    <hosting>Hosting Web</hosting>
```

But here it gets tricky since the `<velocidad>` element should be contained in a `<conexion>` element, according to the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT conexion (tipo,velocidad)>
<!ATTLIST conexion tipo (fibra|cobre) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST velocidad valor (100|300) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT tipo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT velocidad (#PCDATA)>
```

However, there is no parent element for `<conexion`>, so it cannot be part any valid XML document whose root element is `<empresa>`.